# How to avoid string interpolation in Ruby HEREDOC multi line string

Tags: ruby

I have a multi line HEREDOC such as this:

```
c = <<-MYTEXT
{ 'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}" }
MYTEXT
```

This raises the error

```
undefined method `days' for 2:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

I don't want Ruby to interpolate the string and write the value of 2 days in integer, but instead I want it to write exactly the string #{2.days.to_i}

If I escape the # and the \ write it like

```
{ 'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=\#\{2.days.to_i\}\" }
```

it works, but imagine a long text with many #{} string interpolations, ugly.

Any smarter way of doing this?

Comment: "it works" - what is your definition of "works"? This would not interpolate the value in the string.

Comment: The interpolation seem to work just fine. The problem is that `2.days` raises a NoMethodError, i.e. the `days` method is unknown. You probably forgot to `require "active_support"` which provides this [extension](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-numeric-time). (alternatively use `60*60*24*2` or hard code `172800`)

Comment: I guess I havent explained my intention clear enough.  I don't want the string to be interpolated, I want it to be written exactly as #{2.days.to_i}".   I am updating the question to be more precise.

Comment: Yes, you haven't explained this at all (in the first version). The question literally says "how to use string interpolation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "disable" interpolation by using single-quoted strings

```rb
c = <<-'MYTEXT'
{ 'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}" }
MYTEXT
```